# Simple Function Design

Tags: functions

I want to design a function that satisfies the following:

generally speaking, $f(x) = y$

$$f(5.51) = 1$$
$$f(95.31) = 200$$

How can I go about designing the function to satisfy these requirements?

Comment: Hmm, what kind of shapes would you like it to be? Is it convex/concave? Polynomial? Any symmetries? Or would you like to fit the data into certain functions? [Always hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>...]

Comment: Next time please use TeX formatting as well as refraining from possibly offensive language.

Comment: Sure thing. I'd like this function to be exponential, or at least that general shape.

Comment: The trouble is, the two "rules" f(5.51) = 1 and f(95.31) = 200  are obviously useless when x is not 5.51 or 95.31.  Do you want us to guess what y is when x = 5.5?  There are too little data points to use [(non-linear) regression analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Nonlinear_regression).

Comment: I seem to be confusing people about the purpose of my question. Basically, I'm designing this function so I can visually lay out elements in a web form such that they are aesthetically pleasing as well as precisely fitting numerical requirements. Whether or not that knowledge will please or enrage you is beyond me.

Comment: @nbubis: If "brainfart" offends you, then you need to be less easily offended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a function of the form $f(x)=a e^{bx}$ then simply solve for $a$ and $b$ using your data points.

If you want a polynomial function of degree $n$ then you'll need $n+1$ data points. With two data points, you get a polynomial of degree 1 (at most).

Comment: Awesome. That's great. Unfortunately I can't vote this solution up because I don't have enough reputation. I'm also now wondering how could I do the same thing using a polynomial?

Comment: @Dan, I've edited my answer.

Comment: The last statement sounds good, y=mx+c will suffice here, (m,c are to be resolved from the given two conditions).

Comment: Ah, cool. Let's add $$f(40) = 10$$

Comment: I mentioned "the given two conditions". With n given conditions, we need n degree polynomial, right?

Comment: With 3 conditions, wouldn't that mean we need a 2 degree polynomial? And is non-linear regression analysis the general answer to this question?

Comment: @Dan: You *can* accept the answer, though (which will increase your reputation).

Comment: My question hasn't been fully answered yet, but sure, might as well.

Comment: @Dan $n$ data points can be exactly matched by a unique polynomial of degree no greater than $n-1$. Regression analysis can do different things, but it is **not** guaranteed that the resulting curve hits your data points -- or any of them at all. The act of finding a curve that goes through each point exactly is called *interpolation*; the act of finding a curve that gets really as close as possible to *all* data points is called *regression*. You need to provide more details on what you want; with three data points, one can fit an infinite number of curves through or near them.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. I ended up using exponential interpolation using my boundary points because I wanted them to be exact. The ones in the middle only had to be close.